# Django Nginx uWSGI 502 Bad Gateway always

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have been following the http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

and went up to the

> http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#running-the-django-application-with-uwsgi-and-nginx

and started the uwsgi --socket mysite.sock --module mysite.wsgi --chmod-socket=664 it is started but when i load my webpage on browser getting **502 Bad Gateway**

Django version 1.10.2

error is

> error] 25444#25444: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused)
>   while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: mytest.com,
>   request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:8001", host:
>   "127.0.0.1:8000"

What could be the issue ?

```
# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name mytest.com; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 175M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/karesh/tutorial/uwsgi-tutorial/mysite/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/karesh/tutorial/uwsgi-tutorial/mysite/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  unix:/home/karesh/tutorial/uwsgi-tutorial/mysite/mysite.sock;
        include     /home/karesh/tutorial/uwsgi-tutorial/mysite/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

uwsgi_params file inside project directory

```
uwsgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
uwsgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

uwsgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
uwsgi_param  PATH_INFO          $document_uri;
uwsgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
uwsgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

uwsgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
uwsgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

Comment: As that error shows, nginx is trying to connect via a port, not a socket. You should show your nginx configuration.

Comment: I have done exactly like in the tutorial. my mysite_nginx.conf linked inside sites-enabled.

Comment: Did you restart nginx after you changed its configuration?

Comment: Yes I tried many times. Previously I have installed apache2 and removed it. is there anything that will cause issue.

Comment: Nginx is not seeing the changes in your config. Are you sure it's linked to `sites-enabled`? If it is, `sudo service nginx force-reload` or `restart`.

Comment: eh, you actually have to replace mysite.com with your own

Answer (score 0):

A few things, that could help you:
1) Add user, that runs uWSGI, to `nginx` group
2) On CentOS with enabled SE the best way to put socket is a directory under `/run`
3) Set socket permissions to `<your_user>:nginx`(in other words - set permission for socket for your user and for nginx group.

These steps normally helps me to figure out with permissions error.